# Best way to display Javascript/Div based hover windows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

I'm talking about the [Ibox](http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox/) sort. I.e, user clicks a link and a small javascript based div hovers up containing a small form or such.

I will want to give users a `<script>` tag which they would place in their website. Then, they would put the required javascript function in their `<a href>` tag which they want to use for displaying the form. E.g they would put:

```
<a href="javascript:mysite_signUpForm();">
Create an account on [My site's name]</a>
```

Here mysite would be replaced by the name of my website, obviously.

The main requirement here is that it should be able to display off-site urls in the form. I.e, it should receive a url and load up the contents of that url in its div. Also, changing the background/border color, etc should be easy. And the more visually appealing, the better.

Any suggestions?

Also, if its height will be expanded/reduced as more content is loaded/hidden, it would be best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you use jquery, you could use the [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) plugin. So, once you do that, you can just make the link like so:

```
<a href="http://site.name.com/page.html" rel="facebox">Link content</a>
```

Then intialise the plugin like so:

```
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
```

This will load the remote content at *site.name.com/page.html* in the div and show it.

Apart from this, there are [loads](http://webtecker.com/2008/02/26/8-ajax-lightbox-scripts/) of [other](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) lighbox plugins for jquery.